# Pubnub history; last value of each light

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I'm trying to "upgrade" [Raspberry Pi Smart House Tutorial (Part 2)](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-08-04-building-raspberry-pi-smart-house-part-2/) in its Web interface part. For now, when you open the [Web interface](http://pubnub.github.io/pi-house/) (this one is directly from tutorial) you get default values of sliders set to 0. Is it somehow possible to read the history of a channel (that part I know is possible, at least for the last 100 messages) and extract last values for each light; history looks like this:

```
{"item": "light-living", "brightness": 6}
{"item": "light-living", "brightness": 9}
{"item": "light-porch", "brightness": 60}
{"item": "fireplace", "brightness": 4}
{"item": "light-porch", "brightness": 88}
{"item": "light-living", "brightness": 4}
{"item": "fireplace", "brightness": 7}
{"item": "light-porch", "brightness": 84}
```

So, I would have to extract last set value "brightness" for each "item"; in this case light-living, light-porch and fireplace. Can this be done?

JavaScript is used for communication with PubNub.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would recommend that each device have its own channel. Then you just need to retrieve last message of each device's channel. Make sense?

Comment: Did this work for you? Some other solution you came up with maybe? Let us know.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't work on this up until last few days. Your comment was very helpful. I just decided that instead of publishing items seperately, I could always publish all items with values to one channel like: {item_name1: "value1", item_name2: "value2", ...}. The problem now is getting history.

Comment: Let me know your history issues. Create a new SO question though.

Comment: I created it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979014/pubnub-history-wait-for-response
Thanks for helping.