# pubnub history; wait for response

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I would need some help with pubnub history. I have to retrive last message (object) of the channel in JavaScript. So I do the following:

```
var vrednosti = {};

var debug = 1;

getHistory = function(){
    pubnub.history({
        channel: settings.channel,
        callback: function(m){
            var msg = m[0];
            var obj = msg[0];
            for (var key in obj){
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)){
                    if(inputs[key].id=='door') inputs[key].checked = vrednosti[key] = obj[key];
                    else inputs[key].value = vrednosti[key] = obj[key];
                    if(debug) console.log("history:",vrednosti)
                }
            }           
        },
    count : 1,
    });
}

getHistory();

console.log("recorded history in var vrednosti!", vrednosti)

setTimeout(function(){
    if(debug) console.log("recorded history in var vrednosti!", vrednosti)
}, 1000);
```

So this produces the following result:

```
recorded history in var vrednosti! Object {  }
history: Object { door: true }
history: Object { door: true, lightLiving: "844" }
history: Object { door: true, lightLiving: "844", lightPorch: "395" }
recorded history in var vrednosti! Object { door: true, lightLiving: "844", lightPorch: "395" }
```

So the problem is, that code after the "getHistory();" is executed before I get an answer from callback function. Is there a way to force the wait on callback?

Comment: No.  You need to use callbacks or promises.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks are asynchronous. It means that you must move all code you want to execute after in callback function.

```
var vrednosti = {};

var debug = 1;

getHistory = function(){
    pubnub.history({
        channel: settings.channel,
        callback: function(m){
            var msg = m[0];
            var obj = msg[0];
            for (var key in obj){
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)){
                    if(inputs[key].id=='door') inputs[key].checked = vrednosti[key] = obj[key];
                    else inputs[key].value = vrednosti[key] = obj[key];
                    if(debug) console.log("history:",vrednosti)
                }
            }

            console.log("recorded history in var vrednosti!", vrednosti)

            setTimeout(function(){
                if(debug) console.log("recorded history in var vrednosti!", vrednosti)
            }, 1000); 
        },
    count : 1,
    });
}

getHistory();
```

Comment: ok, i didn't post the whole code in example, but this means that I have to put everything inside pubnub.history callback? And with everything I mean pubnub.subscribe, pubnub.publish and EventListeners?

Comment: It depends on what other your code is related with. Scripts that have nothing to do with Pubnub history you can leave on the same place, but everything that depends on the result from callback you must put in callback function.

Comment: @TheoryX - It might feel more natural to create some custom functions for your subscribe, publish, etc and just call them directly from your history callback or wherever else you need to.